# Apache mod_deflate not compressing javascript and css files?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, gzip, mod-deflate, deflate

```
"GET /Symfony/web/app.php/app/dashboard HTTP/1.1" 4513/37979 (11%)
"GET /Symfony/web/css/application.css HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /Symfony/web/js/application.js HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /Symfony/web/js/highcharts.js HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
"GET /Symfony/app/Resources/public/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" -/- (-%)
```

Don't know if there is something wrong with my configuration, but the **no compression for css and js seems strange** to me.

However both css and js are already minified. Here is Apache relevant section in cong/httpd.conf:

```
# Deflate
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

DeflateCompressionLevel 9

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# IE5.x and IE6 get no gzip, but allow 7+
BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s7 !no-gzip

Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

DeflateFilterNote Input instream
DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio
LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
CustomLog logs/deflate.log deflate
```

Comment: Helpful additional information: With what browser? (Your conf seems to allow IE 7 only, not 7+ as the comment states.) What mime type does it see the files as? A copy/paste of headers gathered with WireShark would be best of all.

Comment: @SilverbackNet a modern one (say Firefox latest).

Comment: What log is your data from ? 

Are those files served with a 304 Not modified header ? This would explain why there is no file size at all.

Answer (score 0):

set your .htaccess too. This is just example:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary

#Dealing with proxy servers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Remember to add media file format mp4, mpg, mpeg, swf, mp3, ogg...